# Run a test multiple times from another test

Tags: python, testing, module, automation, testng

I have a module `testrun.py` which runs all the tests. One of the tests is `SWStatus`
such that

```
class HWStatus(myTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SWStatus, self).__init__()

    def setup(self):
        return

    def work(self):
    """
    doing my work here
    """
```

To run this test  I do `python testrun.py SWStatus` and it gives me the results.

I want to create a `HWStatus` test such that it will actually run `SWStatus` test 10 times.

```
class HWStatus(myTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SWStatus, self).__init__()

    def setup(self):
        return

    def work(self):
    """
    run SWStatus test 10 times
    """
```

So if I do `python testrun.py HWStatus`, it should actually do `python testrun.py SWStatus` 10 times.
What is the way to implement such a functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use subprocess. Open the test script as a subprocess and then poll() it to determine when the test is completed and you can start it again.

```
for i in xrange(10):
    args = ['python', 'testrun.py', 'HWStatus']
    p = subprocess.Popen(args)
    while p.poll() != 0:
        time.sleep(amount_of_time)
```

Comment: hey thanks @RudyS. I'm using a variable `status` in `work` classmethod of SWStatus. It's True or False depending on some checks. Can I have access to  a variable of class `SWStatus` in class `HWStatus`? Thanks